# 1981 Putnam problem A-3 : Differentiating under a double integral?

Tags: integration, contest-math

I was trying some old problems and got stuck on this one. Then when I looked at the answer there was a step I could not understand. Perhaps you can explain it to me.

**A-3** Find

$ \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[ e^{-t}\int_0^t \int_0^t \frac{e^x - e^y}{x - y}dx dy \right]$

or show that the limit does not exist.

**Solution** Let $G(t)$ be the double integral.  Then $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\frac{G(t)}{e^t} = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\frac{G'(t)}{e^t}$ by L'Hopital.  Then
$$G'(t) = \int_0^t \frac{e^x-e^t}{x-t}dx+ \int_0^t \frac{e^y-e^t}{y-t}dy$$
so
$$G'(t) = 2\int_0^t \frac{e^x-e^t}{x-t}dx.$$

Then, the answer continues to show that  $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{G'(t)}{e^t}=\infty$ since,
$$\frac{G'(t)}{2e^t} = \int_0^t \frac{e^{x-t}-1}{x-t}dx = \int_0^t\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}dy > \int_1^t\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}dy > \left(1-e^{-1}\right)log\,t.$$
My question is how $G'(t)$ was found.  I understand the rest of the solution.  I understand differentiating under the integral in the one dimensional case, but I do not understand how it works in the case of a double integral (which I assume is what is being done here), and I couldn't produce the answer's result.

Comment: G(t) is an integral over a square [0, t] x [0, t].  So G(t+dt) is an integral over a slightly larger square, which can be decomposed into the original square plus two strips of width dt and a square of area dt^2 which can be neglected in the limit.  The expression for G'(t) is the sum of the integrals over those strips, divided by dt, in the limit as dt approaches zero.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. I think I understand now.

Comment: You might want to use `$$..math...$$` instead of `$\displaystyle...math...$`. The double dollar sign puts you in displaystyle, and it renders better. It also means you don't have to leave the blank lines to interrupt a paragraph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $$F(y,t)=\int_0^t \frac{e^x-e^y}{x-y} dx.$$ Then your $G(t)$ is  $$G(t)=\int_0^t F(y,t) dy.$$

Then  $$G'(t)=F(t,t)+\int_0^t \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} (y,t) dy$$
$$=\int_0^t \frac{e^x-e^t}{x-t} dx + \int_0^t\frac{e^t -e^y}{t-y} dy  .$$